# Change of variable in abstract notations

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, change-of-variable

We define a curve $\Gamma_a$ parametrized by its arc length $s$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma = \{x_a(s), z(s)_a | s \in (0,L) \}
\end{equation}
were $(z,x)$ is the coordinate system under study. So $z$ is drawn as function of $x$: $z(x)$.
The first derivative of $z$ can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z_a}{\partial x_a} = \frac{\partial z_a}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x_a} = \frac{z'_a}{x'_a}
\end{equation}
The prime $(')$ here is defined with respect to $s$. The professor said that we can generalize and in better way this way of writing by introducing that $\tilde{z}$ in terms of x such that (because x_a is invertable):

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{z}_a(x) = z_a(x_a^{-1}(x)) \ \ \ \text{as} \ \  s = x_a^{-1}(x)
\end{equation}
then a better treatment with partial derivative is:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \tilde{z}_a}{\partial x} (x) = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial x_a}{\partial s}} \frac{\partial z_a}{\partial s}(x_a^{-1}(x))
\end{equation}
I didn't get how did he get $s=x_a^{-1}(x)$ and why do we need to do such step? because my step already works but the high mathematical level by using $\tilde{z}$ is still somehow weird?

Comment: Your prof is suggesting a way of avoiding the confusion in your first five lines. You use $z$ in two senses, a function of $s$ and a function of $x$. The prof points out that we have two functions $z$ and $\bar{z}$ related by $z(s)=\bar{z}(x(s))$. So he can then properly apply the Chain Rule. [I've omitted all the embroidery with ${}_a$]